# Jasmine calling function with ajax returned value

Tags: ajax, jasmine

I want to test the "addGroup" function  using Jasmine. I get the following error:

Error: Expected spy modifyMyHtml to have been called.at null.

I don't know what is the best way to test the addGroup function. Please HELP.....

```
var myRecord = {

   addGroup: function(groupNumber) {

        $.when(myRecord.getHtml())
        .done(function(returnedHtml){
            myRecord.modifyMyHtml(returnedHtml);           
        });
    },

    getHtml: function() {
        return $.ajax({url: "myHtmlFile.html", dataType: "html" });
    },
    // adds options and events to my returned HTML
    modifyMyHtml: function(returnedHtml) {
        $('#outerDiv').html(returnedHtml);
        var myOptions = myRecord.getOptions();
        $('#optionsField').append(myOptions);
        myRecord.bindEventsToDiv();
    },
}
```

====JASMINE TEST

```
describe("Configure Record page", function() {
    var fixture;

    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = "/test/" ;
    jasmine.getFixtures().load("myHtmlFile.html");
    fixture = $("#jasmine-fixtures").html();

    describe("addGroup", function(){
        beforeEach(function() {
            var groupNumber = 0;
            spyOn(myRecord, "getHtml").andCallFake(function(){
                return $.Deferred().promise();
            });
            spyOn(myRecord, "modifyMyHtml");
            myRecord.addGroup(groupNumber);
        });

        it("Should call getHtml", function() {
            expect(myRecord.getHtml).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it("Should call modifyMyHtml", function() {             
            expect(myRecord.modifyMyHtml).toHaveBeenCalled();  ==>FAILS
        });         
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to resolve the promise before you return em in your `andCallFake`.

```
spyOn(myRecord, "getHtml").andCallFake(function(){
  return $.Deferred().resolve ().promise();
});
```

Btw. you should not test that the function on the object you wanna test are called, but that the html in the DOM are set with the right html

```
it("Should call modifyMyHtml", function() {    
   spyOn(myRecord, "getHtml").andCallFake(function(){
      return $.Deferred().resolveWith(null, 'returnedHtml').promise();
   });         
   expect($('#outerDiv').html).toEqual('returnedHtml')
});
```